# Is there a site that lets you publish code where people can submit issues? (E.g. Github)

Tags: share, publish

My company has a project where we need to share an SDK we have developed with initially a limited set of developers, but ultimately all developers, so that they can:
 - download the SDK
 - submit issues
 - browse and post to a forum where other developers troubleshoot issues
 - post reference clients that use the code which developers can download, contribute to...

Note: We don't want/need other developers to edit/contribute to the SDK itself. My company  will retain control and edit/publish the SDK.

I am seeing sites like GitHub but I'm not sure it's the right fit. Could GitHub meet my needs? Are there other sites that might do this better?

Answer (score 2):

Github provides private repositories for a fee. There's also Bitbucket which also does Git and is now part of the Attlassian suit it provides private repositories for free but the number of users is limited; LaunchPad does the same with Bazaar instead of Git, Microsoft has Codeplex and TFS on the azure cloud, and I'm sure there's a gaggle of providers for other version control platforms.

In short there are many, many options, one of them is sure to fit your needs and budget.

Comment: Thank you - this is excellent perspective. We already use JIRA which is part of Atlassian for bug tracking so perhaps BitBucket and JIRA can work  together?

Comment: The company I worked with had a plugin that would link git commits to Jira issues based on the comment (the issue number needed to be specified in a line by itself or something like that, don't quite remember.) This was using our own servers. Atlassian may have developed better integration since specially if you use their online offerings (i.e. hosted on their servers) do your homework drop them a message :-)